# symfony createQueryBuilder Sql query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have table entity - developer and user. And in user I have three roles ROLE_DEVELOPER ROLE_FREELANCER and ROLE_COMPANY. All role each begin user and if this is developer in user have ManyToOne developer. And in Developer if developer in company(ROLE_DEVELOPER) his have team if not have team this is developer single and have ROLE_FREELANCER. And every team have manager this manager is entity user and in entity user have team. user.team.id = developer.team.id - all developers of this manager. And I need all developer who have this skills array and not have this some tags. And if this is ROLE_DEVELOPER I need find his manager if not that's it. I try with sql but I need this is do it with createQueryBuilder
How create for $db = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder(); this query?
sql query:

```
    SELECT u.email , if(u.role='ROLE_DEVELOPER', m.email, u.email) as send_email, m.unsubscribe_date as uns_date
FROM users as u
left join developers as d on d.id=u.developer_id
left join users as m on m.teams_id=d.team_id
WHERE u.unsubscribe_date <= now()
and d.skills like '%php%'
and d.skills like '%java%'
and u.role in ('ROLE_FREELANCER', 'ROLE_DEVELOPER')
and d.tags not like '%india%'
and d.tags not like '%black_list%'
and (m.unsubscribe_date <= now() OR m.unsubscribe_date is null)
group by send_email
```

it works but there is no group by send_email

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $q = $em->createQuery(

    'SELECT u.email as u_eamil, m.email, u.roles, m.unsubscribeDate as uns_date
    FROM ArtelProfileBundle:Users as u
    left join ArtelProfileBundle:Developer as d WITH d.id=u.developer
    left join ArtelProfileBundle:Users as m WITH m.teams=d.teams
    WHERE u.unsubscribeDate <= :today
    and d.skills like \'%php%\'
    and d.skills like \'%java%\'
    and u.roles in (\'ROLE_FREELANCER\', \'ROLE_DEVELOPER\')
    and d.tags not like \'%india%\'
    and d.tags not like \'%black_list%\'
    and (m.unsubscribeDate <= :today OR m.unsubscribeDate is null)
    GROUP BY send_email
    '
    )
    ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime())
    ;
    $entities = $q->getArrayResult();
```

this is not work and not understand why:

```
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Users', 'u')
        ->select('u.email as u_eamil, m.email, u.roles, m.unsubscribeDate as uns_date')
        ->leftJoin('u.developer', 'd') //this works assuming the doctrine mappings are correct on the $developer property in the ArtelProfileBundle:Users' entity
        ->leftJoin('d.teams', 'm')
        ->where('u.unsubscribeDate <= :today')
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('d.skills', '%php%'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('d.skills', '%java%'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('ROLE_FREELANCER', 'ROLE_DEVELOPER'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->notLike('d.tags', '%india%'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->notLike('d.tags', '%black_list%'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX('m.unsubscribeDate <= :today', $qb->expr()->isNull('m.unsubscribeDate')))
        ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime());
    $entities = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

[Syntax Error] line 0, col 203: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '%'
```

**SOLVED**
I need if in users ROLE_DEVELOPER get email manager for team which is developer. for this I create custom dql, add this dql in config

```
        dql:
        string_functions:
            IF: Artel\ProfileBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\IfFunction
```

and create

```
class IfFunction extends FunctionNode
{
private $expr = array();

public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
{
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
    $this->expr[] = $parser->ConditionalExpression();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->expr[] = $parser->ArithmeticExpression();
    }

    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
}

public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
{
    return sprintf('IF(%s, %s, %s)',
        $sqlWalker->walkConditionalExpression($this->expr[0]),
        $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->expr[1]),
        $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->expr[2]));
}
}
```

and my query builder

```
     public function notificationProject($paramFetcher)
     {
     $em = $this->getEntityManager();
     $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Users', 'u')
        ->select('u.id, u.email as u_email, m.email, d.skills, u.roles, m.unsubscribeDate as uns_date')
        ->addSelect("IF(u.roles = 'ROLE_DEVELOPER', m.email, u.email) as send_email")

        ->leftJoin('u.developer', 'd') //this works assuming the doctrine mappings are correct on the $developer property in the ArtelProfileBundle:Users' entity
        ->leftJoin('d.teams', 't')
        ->leftJoin('t.users', 'm')
        ->where('u.unsubscribeDate <= :today');
    foreach($paramFetcher[1] as $skill){
        if ($skill)
        $qb
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('d.skills', $qb->expr()->literal('%"' . $skill . '"%')));
    }
    $qb
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('u.roles', array('ROLE_FREELANCER', 'ROLE_DEVELOPER')));

    foreach($paramFetcher[0] as $tag){
        if ($tag)
        $qb
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->notlike('d.tags', $qb->expr()->literal('%"' . $tag . '"%')));
    }
    $qb
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX('m.unsubscribeDate <= :today', $qb->expr()->isNull('m.unsubscribeDate')))
        ->groupBy('send_email')
        ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime());
    $entities = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second query you are not selecting the same thing. (Who is `send_email` in the second query?)

If you really want to unleash the power of the query builder you can write something like:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager('ArtelProfileBundle:Users'); 

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('u');

$qb->select('u.email as u_eamil, m.email as send_email, u.roles, m.unsubscribeDate as uns_date')
   ->leftJoin('u.developer', 'd') //this works assuming the doctrine mappings are correct on the $developer property in the ArtelProfileBundle:Users' entity
   ->leftJoin('d.teams', 'm')     
   ->where('u.unsubscribeDate <= :today')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('d.skills', '%php%'))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('d.skills', '%java%'))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('u.role',array('ROLE_FREELANCER', 'ROLE_DEVELOPER')))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->notLike('d.tags', '%india%'))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->notLike('d.tags', '%black_list%'))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX('m.unsubscribeDate <= :today', $qb->expr()->isNull('m.unsubscribeDate')))
   ->groupBy('send_email')
   ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime());
$entities = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: maybe $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('u'); ?

Comment: and I not understand this ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in(array('ROLE_FREELANCER', 'ROLE_DEVELOPER'))) I have field in user - roles. I update my question

Comment: have error - No alias was set before invoking getRootAlias().

Comment: send_email - this is manager email. If find many ROLE_DEVELOper he has on manager and need remove duplicate help with GROUP BY send_email

Comment: I think I have to edit my query a bit. It was from memory, and I didn't test it. You are right this `$qb->expr()->in(` has to arguments, I added the field. I've corrected some of it. LEt me know if you find anymore mistakes and if it works.